# How to write a VS Extension which launches the debugger and executes code?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-extensions

I am sure some of you have heared of ncrunch and almost every professional developer of resharper - both of those VS extensions are able to launch VS into debugger mode.

I was wondering how to achieve such a thing since i thought that it would be pretty useful for an open source project i've got in mind.

Google isn't very helpful with such keywords so i figured i might just see if someone here has a clue how to do this.

#### Update 1:

https://github.com/fareloz/AttachToolbar/blob/master/ToolbarController.cs seems relevant regarding attaching to running process

Comment: There are many open source VS extensions with such features implemented, like AxoCover, https://github.com/axodox/AxoCover So even if Google does not yield useful results, digging such code base would help.

Comment: @LexLi you need to be aware of a code base in order to get use out of it, which you won't find unless you find it randomly/through search, but thanks for the link

Comment: Often you need to pay attention to the way you search. For example, ReSharper allows you to debug unit test cases, which I think is the reason you listed it as an example above. Then in your search you should focus on unit testing related open source VS extensions and no doubt AxoCover should come at top of that list.